# How to set the default working directory of my R project to my project directory?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have started to use R Projects, but when I start a new project (either in a new or existing directory), the default working directory is not set to that folder (I thought that should be the case, right? I read it [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects)).

What happens instead is that it goes to my home folder, like:

```
>getwd()
[1] "/home/user"
```

I can change my working directory manually to the project folder with `setwd()`, but when I restart RStudio, it is going back to the home folder again, not the project folder.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Pretty basic question probably, but I have not found the answer yet, and I am new to the projects part of RStudio, so I am not sure if this is an issue in my settings or something...

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: In case you accidentally `setwd(other/path/thanprojectdir)` then you can revert within Rstudio menu `-> Session, Set Working Directory -> To Project directory`

Comment: I am having a similar problem that when I open Markdowns in a Project, the working directory of the Markdown is where that file is located (subdirectory), not where the Project is located. I tried Lefkios's suggestion and while this did set my Console's working directory to the project, the working directory of Markdown did not change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. For some reason I had `setwd("~")` in my Rprofile.site document... I removed it and tried again with starting new projects in RStudio. Now `getwd()` shows the correct folder of the current project.

Answer (score 1):

> but when I restart RStudio, it is going back to the home folder again, not the project folder.

This shouldn’t happen. The [RStudio documentation for projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) states:

> When a project is opened within RStudio the following actions are taken: […]
>
> - The current working directory is set to the project directory.

I can verify that this works as documented on macOS with RStudio 1.0.153. If this isn’t working for you, you should report a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I already thought that should be the case indeed

Answer (score -1):

To do it directly:

```
setwd("/PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER")
```

or:

Files -> (search and select your folder) -> More -> Set as working directory